# jquery replace > character on html code

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I'm tring to change breadcrumbs arrow > (`&gt`) to » using jquery.

`<div id="breadcrumbs"> 
<a title="Go to cbc." href="http://cbcsales.co.il/newsite" class="home">Home</a> 
&gt; testpage</div>`

I tried using following jquery. But  tag is missing. It is replace `<a>` tag `>` character. Help me. Thanks

```
jQuery("#breadcrumbs").text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace('>', '»');
    });
```

Comment: Why are you trying to replace a tag when it is clearly text? `text.replace('&gt;', '»')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `replace` on the element itself, not within a function:

#### Demo

```js
jQuery("#breadcrumbs").html(
    jQuery("#breadcrumbs").html().replace('&gt;', '»')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="breadcrumbs"> 
    <a title="Go to cbc." href="http://cbcsales.co.il/newsite" class="home">Home</a>
    &gt; testpage
</div>
```

Comment: @putvande well spotted, fixed.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But home link is missing.

Comment: @user3575182 see my updated answer. You need to use `html()` instead of `text()`.

Comment: Ohh there is a problem. It is replacing in only one &gt; second one is not changing.

Comment: @user3575182 there is only one in your question.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This site has another breadcrumbs. Not change second &gt;<div id="breadcrumbs">
<a title="Go to cbc." href="#" class="home">Home</a>&gt; <a title="Go to טרה." href="#" class="post post-page">טרה</a> &gt; יוגורט</div>

Answer (score 2):

Use .html() at .text() like this

```
jQuery("#breadcrumbs").html(jQuery("#breadcrumbs").html().replace("&gt;", "&raquo;"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function was almost right, but you had to replace `>` with the `&gt;` you've had written and `.text` for `.html`:

```
jQuery("#breadcrumbs").html(function(index, html) {
    return html.replace(/&gt;/g, '»');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezd70v7h/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = 'some+multi+word+string'.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `#breadcrumbs` attribute inside the Jquery with the `.home`. 
You will see that the link is still there.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bill123/53L5k89d/)